# Convert number from text field to proper USD

Tags: javascript

I have a script that on leaving a text field

```
onblur="forA();"
```

converts a user input number to "number + USD" but it looks very unprofessional.  The script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function forA()
{
document.getElementById('field1').value = 
document.getElementById('field2').value +" USD";
}
</script>
```

So this converts "`12345.75`" to "`12345.75 USD`".  Ughh.

Do you know how I can convert this number to its proper self? `12345.75` to `$12,345.75`

My second, related question is in the same vain...

onclick="document.getElementById('field1').value = 
(Math.round((parseFloat(document.getElementById('11091').value,2)*100))/100 + 
Math.round((parseFloat(document.getElementById('1254.75').value,2)*100))/100).toFixed(2);"

Can the value from field1 (12345.75) also be converted to "$12,345.75"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I format the text entered into an HTML textfield like currency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162711/how-can-i-format-the-text-entered-into-an-html-textfield-like-currency)

Answer (score 1):

```
function forA() 
{ 
   document.getElementById('field1').value = "$" + addCommas(document.getElementById('field2').value) +" USD"; 
} 

function addCommas(nStr)
{
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

Check out an example at: http://jsfiddle.net/CS67m/1/

The comma script is from: http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic.html
I have used it before and it has worked like a charm.

Here is an **updated** example for the additional functionality you requested:
http://jsfiddle.net/CS67m/3/

Html

```
Number 1<input id="field1" value="$1,230.12"/><br>
Number 2<input id="field2" value="$1,230.12"/><br>
Sum<input id="sum" readonly=true/>
<button id="submit">Add</button>
```

JS

```
function forA()
{
  document.getElementById('sum').value = "$" + addCommas(getNumericValue('field1') + getNumericValue('field2')) +" USD";
}

function addCommas(nStr)
{
    nStr += '';
    x = nStr.split('.');
    x1 = x[0];
    x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}

function getNumericValue(id)
{
    return stripAlphaChars(document.getElementById(id).value);
}
//Source: http://www.27seconds.com/kb/article_view.aspx?id=31
function stripAlphaChars(pstrSource)
{
var m_strOut = new String(pstrSource);
    m_strOut = m_strOut.replace(/[^0-9\\.]/g, '');

    return parseFloat(m_strOut);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This was extremly helpful.  I did however run into an unexpected glitch.  2 of the newly formatted number are calculated on a "click" event but because they are now formatted as $x,xxx.xx I am getting a NaN.  Is it possible to run the formatting on the fields after the addition of the raw numbers?

Comment: @G If I understand correctly your taking two fields adding them, however because the field is formatted like "$ xxxx.xx USD it won't let you add them.

Comment: @G I updated my original answer, I hope you are still watching.  Please accept if it fits your needs.